# Java GetstringMethod

Tags: java

The assignment:

> Write a program (`Greetings`) that prompts the user to enter the first name, the last name, and year of birth, then it returns a greetings message 
>   in proper format (see the example below).
>   Create a method(s) that accept the scanner and a prompt as parameters and return the user input. A separate method should accept the user input results as parameters, format and print the results. No print statement or scanner input should happen inside `main()`. Here is an example dialogue with the user:
>
> Please enter your first name:
>   tom
>   Please enter your last name:
>   cruise
>   Please enter your year of birth:
>   1962
>   Greetings, T. Cruise! You are about 53 years old.

I finished the code, but right now it is giving me a compilation error. How do i fix it?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Greetings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner newscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ask = ("Please enter your first name: ");
        String ask2 = ("Please enter your last name: ");
        String ask3 = ("Please enter your year of birth: ");


public static String getString(Scanner newscanner, String ask, String ask2, String ask3){
    System.out.println(ask);
    String first = newscanner.next();
    String firstletter = first.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() ;
    return firstletter;

    System.out.println(ask2);
    String second = newscanner.next();
    int x = second.length();
    String y = second.substring(0, x).toLowerCase();
    String lastname = y.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    return lastname;

    System.out.println(ask3);
    int third = newscanner.nextInt();        
    int age = (2015 - third);
    return age

    System.out.println("Greetings, "+ firstletter + ". " + lastname+"!" +" You are about " + age + " years old");
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Hard to read, but I think you actually have the `getString()` method *inside* your `main()` method - it needs to be after it, and only be called from inside `main()`, not defined there.